# Why Reflection.Emit is not available on Xamarin.Android portable project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, portable-class-library, reflection.emit

I know that Android supports JIT so `Reflection.Emit` should be available on that platform. But when I select .NET 4 + Xamarin.Android targets in Portable Class Library project properties I can't use `Reflection.Emit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because Visual Studio adds other platforms ([like iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/#System.Reflection.Emit)) that doesn't support `System.Reflection.Emit` to the target Profile.

[image]

If you want to use this API, go for a [shared project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/)  or use file linking.

Comment: It's a consequence of the same APIs for  Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS in PCL but I still don't understand the reasons why they are made the same.

Comment: A PCL is a library that can be used in all targeted platforms. That's why you have only a the subset of classes/functions that have all selected target frameworks in common.